# Error The work item type Product Backlog Item cannot be found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

Fixed: Turns out I had to change the project to my InheritedProcess containing the ReflectedWorkItemId for it to work. My migration just ran. Thanks for the help!

Please close this!

I'm trying to use this migration tool to test out a migration. I have a source project and target project. Both on ADO and in the same organization. I have created the field "ReflectedWorkItemId" for my organization under an inherited process for SCRUM process as follows:

[image: Org settings with ReflectedWorkItemId]

Error I'm getting is:

```
[12:08:55 INF] !! After removing all found work items there are 134 remaining to be migrated.
[12:08:55 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Task does not contain ReflectedWorkItemId
[12:08:55 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeDeniedOrNotExistException: TF201077: The work item type Product Backlog Item cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeCollection.get_Item(String typeName)
   at MigrationTools.ProcessorEnrichers.TfsValidateRequiredField.ValidatingRequiredField(String fieldToFind, List`1 sourceWorkItems) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\ProcessorEnrichers\TfsValidateRequiredField.cs:line 44
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 122
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
[12:08:55 ERR] WorkItemMigration The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
[12:08:55 INF] Application is shutting down...
[12:08:55 INF] Terminating: Application forcebly closed.
[12:08:55 INF] Application Ending
[12:08:55 INF] The application ran in 00:00:34.4484023 and finished at 02/19/2021 12:08:55
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
  "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/REDACTED/",
    "Project": "SingularPOC",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/REDACTED/",
    "Project": "TargetPOC",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "FieldMaps": [
    {
      "$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2"
      },
      "targetFieldsAndValues": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldBlankMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "targetField": "TfsMigrationTool.ReflectedWorkItemId"
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldValueMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "System.State",
      "targetField": "System.State",
      "defaultValue": "New",
      "valueMapping": {
        "Approved": "New",
        "New": "New",
        "Committed": "Active",
        "In Progress": "Active",
        "To Do": "New",
        "Done": "Closed",
        "Removed": "Removed"
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoFieldMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority",
      "targetField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank",
      "defaultValue": null
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "SourceToTargetMappings": {
        "SourceField1": "TargetField1",
        "SourceField2": "TargetField2"
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldtoTagMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "System.State",
      "formatExpression": "ScrumState:{0}"
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldMergeMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField1": "System.Description",
      "sourceField2": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
      "targetField": "System.Description",
      "formatExpression": "{0} <br/><br/><h3>Acceptance Criteria</h3>{1}",
      "doneMatch": "##DONE##"
    },
    {
      "$type": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "COMPANY.PRODUCT.Release",
      "targetField": "COMPANY.DEVISION.MinorReleaseVersion",
      "pattern": "PRODUCT \\d{4}.(\\d{1})",
      "replacement": "$1"
    },
    {
      "$type": "FieldValuetoTagMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked",
      "pattern": "Yes",
      "formatExpression": "{0}"
    },
    {
      "$type": "TreeToTagMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "toSkip": 3,
      "timeTravel": 1
    }
  ],
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
      "NodeBasePaths": [
        "Product\\Area\\Path1",
        "Product\\Area\\Path2"
      ],
      "WorkItemIDs": null
    }
  ],
  "Version": "11.9",
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
  "Endpoints": {
    "InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
      {
        "Name": "Source",
        "EndpointEnrichers": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Target",
        "EndpointEnrichers": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I have already verified that "Task" does indeed contain the ReflectedWorkItemId

Comment: You said that you created ReflectedWorkItemID (BTW, I recognize the tool that you're using for this :) ) - did you do that in both source and destination project?

Comment: Also, your title and your content don't match - the content talks about ReflectedWorkItemID and the title talks about the work item type not existing - and THAT would have me verifying that the project really does inherit from Scrum so as to have a Product Backlog Item item type.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I created the ReflectedWorkItemId by creating an inherited process for SCRUM in the organization settings. How do I go about creating it in the source and destination project?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole yep you were right. I had to re-verify that the TargetPOC project was indeed SCRUM. It was BASIC before this but I just re-made the project and now getting these fine errors:                                                                                [13:23:45 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Task does not contain ReflectedWorkItemId
[13:23:45 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Product Backlog Item does not contain ReflectedWorkItemId

Comment: Turns out I had to change the project to my InheritedProcess containing the ReflectedWorkItemId for it to work. My migration just ran. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added as an answer so that other folks down the road will see that this has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your project process type to ensure that it inherits Scrum, or Product Backlog Item will not be available as an item type.

Check your project process to ensure that the ReflectedItemId field exists in the destination project.

Comment: Do you mean that all types of workitems (epic, feature, task ... etc.) need to add a field called "ReflectedItemId"?